# HTTPS and Websocket API endpoints on same domain

Tags: express, nginx, websocket

I've got a domain set up using Nginx with Express/Node running in the background.

The domain mainly serves HTTPS traffic but I'd like to serve up some WSS traffic along side.

In my Express app I have set up routes for each of the new endpoints but can't think how best to set these up in Nginx. Do I need to create a server block for each route or is there anything I can do to minimise changes to the config?

So far I have this in Nginx:

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl;

    root /sites/api.domain.tld/app;
    index app.js;

    server_name api.domain.tld;

    location / {

            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;

    }

    gzip on;

    access_log /sites/api.domain.tld/logs/access.log combined;
    error_log /sites/api.domain.tld/logs/error.log error;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain.tld/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain.tld/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

}


server {

    listen 80;

    server_name api.domain.tld;

    if ($host =api.domain.tld) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    return 404;

}
```

I know I need to add the Websocket upgrade configuration:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5020;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
```

Just not sure what the best way to do this is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There should just be one configuration needed in NGINX to forward all appropriate web traffic to your server.  Nothing route-specific should be required in NGINX.  Then, one other configuration is needed for webSocket traffic, again nothing specific to any route or API, just generic webSocket configuration.  If you want people to help you more specifically, you will need to show details of your NGINX config and what you have so far.

Comment: I've added what I have in the conf so far.